# Run function from a different class in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a very simple issue with my react native application, I just want to execute a function everytime a button is clicked, it become complicated when there's separate classes and components.

I have 2 screens `Dashboard` and `Search` and 2 components `Navbar` and `Results`

In Dashboard I grab some user input and store it in `selectedIngredients` variable
and with the `Navbar` component I execute a function located in the same file.

```
<Navbar handle={() => this.switcher()} />
```

This function is where should the magic happens (or maybe in Search.js screen?)

```
  switcher() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Select', {passedData:this.state.selectedIngredients });
    Alert.alert("send data to Search.js")
  }
```

*Select is `Search.js` screen*

Everything workin fine and I move to the expected screen with the expected user input `selectedIngredients`, this is the first render of `Search.js` screen.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.apiCall();
    Alert.alert("did mount search.js")
  }
```

After that I'm stuck because everytime I click on the btn on my `Navbar` and execute the switcher() function, componentDidMount do not run anymore so I have to refresh the page by clicking on another button, this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid because it's bad for UX, like really bad. I am not looking to update `Results` component automatically but just update it with one function.

The code below is not that important it only shows `apiCall` function and render of `Results` component, I don't know if I should put more information. Please someone help

```
  apiCall() {
     fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
            data: responseJson.results,
         });
     }) 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.apiCall();
    Alert.alert("did mount search.js")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>

      <Navbar title="Results" />
      <Results results={this.state.data} /> 

    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My attempt was to add `this.props.apiCall()` in switcher function but got undefined error, something like hey react native! please send this data to `Search.js` screen and when you arrive please execute `apiCall` function, it's located there, not here.

Comment: componentDidMount only run once! You can use componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: @gu-mingfeng thanks so much! it works perfectly but only after the second click!!

Comment: Keep componentDidMount also

Comment: Are you using reactnavigation? if yes you can use `didFocus` event https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

Comment: @gu-mingfeng with didMount there's no user input so it crash :(

Comment: @mohammad-walid I have no idea how to implement that

Comment: You are already using reactnavigation?

Comment: Yes I am, I was thinking about creating another screen with stackNavigator and then handle all the results there because with tabBar it's complicated

Comment: @mohammad-walid here's a link to the repo https://github.com/usfslk/blvck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), in **Search.js** you have to bind [`didFocus`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) listener, so the api will be called every time your screen is focused

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  navigation.addListener( 'didFocus', () => this.apiCall() );
  this.apiCall();
  Alert.alert("did mount search.js")
}
```

Comment: I am using this.props.navigation btw, I think better architectures exist to handle stuff like that. Thanks