# React native: How to run the class from a different screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So i started to use react native very recently and I'm not too sure about how to use a class in a different function.

SO far, I have the app class which works fine but if I go to the HomeScreen and create a variable called: var theApp = new app();

In that case I don't think the componentDidMount and render from the app class are working. That's because when I later create  var thePlace = theApp.getPlace(); I only get the result from the constructor and not the one i should be getting.

I think this link here has similar problem to mine: [Run function from a different class in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324262/run-function-from-a-different-class-in-react-native)

but I don't really understand what the solution is.

Edit:

Here is the code for my App2 class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';




export default class App2 extends React.Component {
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    ready: true,
    where: {lat: null, lng: null},
    error:null
  }

}

getLatitude() {
  return this.state.where.lat;

}
componentDidMount() {
    let geoOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeOut: 20000,
      maximumAge: 60*60
    };
    this.setState({ready:false, error: null });
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoSuccess, this.geoFailure, geoOptions);


}

geoSuccess = (position) => {
  this.setState({ready: true,
    where:{lat: position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude}

  });
}


geoFailure = (err) => {
  this.setState({error: err.message});
}

  render(){

  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
      { !this.state.ready && (
      <Text>Using Geolocation in React Native</Text>
      )}
      {this.state.error &&(
      <Text>{this.state.error}</Text>
      )}
      {this.state.ready && (
      <Text>Latitude: {this.state.where.lat} 
            Longitude: {this.state.where.lng}
      </Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And this is part of the homescreen page:

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import React from 'react';
import App2 from './App2';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';



let thePlace = new App2();
let lat = thePlace.getLatitude();

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>


      <View style={styles.tabBarInfoContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.tabBarInfoText}>
        Show the latitude: {lat}
        </Text>

      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
};
```

In order to get these, I just created a template with the navigation that expo already gives you and I added the app2 file into the screens but that class is not running.

So if I use let lat = thePlace.getLatitude(); it only returns the latitude as null because the app2 doesn't run and it only gives the predefined value from the constructor.

Also, there's already another App function which is:

```
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default function App(props) {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);

  if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

async function loadResourcesAsync() {
  await Promise.all([
    Asset.loadAsync([
      require('./assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
      require('./assets/images/robot-prod.png'),
    ]),
    Font.loadAsync({
      // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
      ...Ionicons.font,
      // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free to
      // remove this if you are not using it in your app
      'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    }),
  ]);
}

function handleLoadingError(error) {
  // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error reporting
  // service, for example Sentry
  console.warn(error);
}

function handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete) {
  setLoadingComplete(true);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Comment: Please add your code, it is difficult to understand your intention without it. Is `var theApp = new app()` meant to open a new screen or mount a component? If so, you need to put the result in your render function. Also, you typically shouldn't call functions from other react component directly.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
/*This is an Example of Calling Other Class Function in React Native*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import React in our project
import { StyleSheet, View, Alert, Platform, Button } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we will need in our project

export default class App extends Component {
  handlerSimpleCall = () => {
    //Calling a function of other class (without arguments)
    new OtherClass().functionWithoutArg();
  };

  handlerArgCall = () => {
    //Calling a function of other class (with argument)
    new OtherClass().functionWithArg('About React');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        }}>
        <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
          <Button
            title="Function Without Argument"
            onPress={this.handlerSimpleCall}
            color="#606070"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
          <Button
            title=" Function With Argument"
            onPress={this.handlerArgCall}
            color="#606070"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class OtherClass extends Component {
  functionWithoutArg = () => {
    //function to be called from default class (without args)
    alert('Function Called Without Argument ');
  };

  functionWithArg = Value => {
    //function to called from default class (with args)
    alert(Value);
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I'm looking for something slightly different. I have a function called homescreen and I'd like to call the class App2 from there but when doing that the render () and componentDidMount will not start